# How to make get method of Object.definyProperty return actual value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a test case:

```
test('changeHash works correctly') {
    const getHashSpy = jest.fn(() => '#/someHash');
    const setHashSpy = jest.fn(hash => hash);
    delete global.window.location;
    global.window = Object.create(window);
    global.window.location = {};
    Object.defineProperty(global.indow.location, 'hash', {
        get:getHashSpy,
        set: setHashSpy,
    });
    let wrapper = mount(component);
    let links = wrapper.find('.link');
    links.forEach((node) => {
    if(node.text()) === 'Go to Profile') {
        node.simulate('click');
        expect(global.window.location.hash).toBe('#/settings');
    }
}
```

The actual method should change the hash of window.location.hash The problem is my window.location.hash is statically returns '#/someHahs' not the actual hash set by the method I am testing. So I am receiving error 'expected: (#/settings) received: (#/someHash)

Comment: Your test doesn't make any sense, it appears that you would want something like `expect(setHashSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWIth('#/settings')`. You defined a getter with a static return is *of course* going to return that unchanging string literal.

Comment: Right, I looked up how to implement mock for window.location.href, so now I need to update that implementation so instead of brute const getHashSpy = jest.fn(() => '#/someHash') I want to return dynamic value.

Comment: Yeah, but you're not asserting anything on your setter mock functions so why even bother? Just make it a regular property (no getter/setter) on the location object you create.

Comment: Why are you trying to mock `global.window.location` in the first place?